# MongoDB - Stitch: Can't make custom user data to appear in userObject.customData

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

When I log with a user the userObject contains empty `customData` object despite saving a document in custom data collection pointing to the app user.

I tried to follow the documentation:

1. In the Users section of Mongo Stitch panel I enabled custom data. I chose database, collection (`users`) and stated `User ID Field` to be `userId`. Then I deployed changes.
2. I have a created and confirmed user.
3. I copied the user's `_id` and from shell (from admin account and context of the relevant db) I ran command `db.users.insertOne({userId: ObjectId('copied_id'), description: "something"})`. It was acknowledged and when I query the collection I see relevant document with `userId` field having correct ObjectId() value.
4. I even tried to set read rights to the `users` collection.

Nonetheless, if I log in with my user, `customData` object is empty. What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same issue here... pebcak :/

I fixed it by setting userId as String, not ObjectId.

Hoping it's not too late ;)

Comment: Amazing. It worked. I'd never try try this myself. This must be a bug, I can't imagine this is intended? Thanks a lot!

Comment: NO WAY!!! This is the solution!!! The userId field that you defined in your Custom User Data section has to contain the id AS STRING not ObjectId(".....")